# Are questions about RPG design on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, design, game-systems

Should questions that ask for help in designing an RPG game, or specific mechanics for an RPG game, be allowed?

Comment: Should this be made an FAQ?

Answer (score 21):

Yes; definitely. As long as they are well scoped questions given other site parameters.

Comment: +1 I agree, it would be absurd to have a site about RPGs where questions about design were off-limits. Subject to the usual caveats about what makes a good question, of course.

Comment: We require good scoping. A question on RPG design must have a specific problem to solve that *can* have a specific answer. Lists, discussion, brainstorming, or "guess what I'm thinking" questions are not acceptable, but they're not acceptable due to their vices, not their topic.